# Reliably identify the class of a serialized Java object

Tags: java, object, serialization, deserialization, identification

I am in need of reliably identifying the class of a serialized object in Java without deserializing it.

So far I have found that the raw data stream will contain the class name. However someone could create a custom class with an arbitrary name to fool the recognition.

Now I am considering implementing a system where the stored data of the object is also checked against a template but this seems cumbersome.

Is there a package that already does this and/or is there a simpler way to reliably identify the class of a serialized Java object?

Comment: What's the problem with de-serializing it?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention this. In the security context I am researching this, if the object is not legitimate it should never be created in memory. Thus my attempt to verify the class of the serialized object without deserializing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at JavaAssist (http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)?  It appears to be able to load class files metadata and make it available without necessarily creating the class.

Comment: Their Serialization API looks perfect.